# problem in validating

Tags: .net, regex, validation

I need to validate certain names in a text box. While validating it should not allow special characters as a first character. But after that it can allow any number of special characters. How to validate. What kind of validation expression can be used for this.

Thanks In Advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want alphabetic letters as the first character, then anything after that:

```
[A-Za-z].*
```

Answer (score 0):

```
\w.*
```

\w matches any "word characters" - letters/digits

Comment: `\w` includes also underscore `_`